# ThreadPoolExecutor: how to limit the queue maxsize?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I am using ThreadPoolExecutor class from the concurrent.futures package

```
def some_func(arg):
    # does some heavy lifting
    # outputs some results

from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=1) as executor:
    for arg in range(10000000):
        future = executor.submit(some_func, arg)
```

but I need to limit the queue size somehow, as I don't want millions of futures to be created at once, is there a simple way to do it or should I stick to queue.Queue and threading package to accomplish this?

Comment: doesn't the queue size is controlled by how many jobs you have submitted to the pool?

Comment: @georgexsh, only partially, because you can't always know how many jobs are still there, when you are submitting the next one.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, wait, FIRST_COMPLETED

limit = 10

futures = set()

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=1) as executor:
    for arg in range(10000000):
        if len(futures) >= limit:
            completed, futures = wait(futures, return_when=FIRST_COMPLETED)
        futures.add(executor.submit(some_func, arg))
```

Comment: How can we achieve this with `executor.map`?

Comment: BTW, the return from wait is backwards here.  It needs to be `done, futures`.

Comment: @NedBatchelder true, tnx, fixed

Comment: @Bob, is there any specific reason condition is `if len(futures) >= limit:`? It could as well be `if len(futures) == limit:`?

Comment: @Djuka, yes, indeed

Comment: `>=` seems more robust if the program changes later on and more tasks are submitted later on within the loop (ok, the limit would be a soft limit then)

Comment: This is definitely better than other solutions.

Answer (score 30):

Python's `ThreadPoolExecutor` doesn't have the feature you're looking for, but the provided class can be easily sub-classed as follows to provide it:

```
from concurrent import futures
import queue

class ThreadPoolExecutorWithQueueSizeLimit(futures.ThreadPoolExecutor):
    def __init__(self, maxsize=50, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ThreadPoolExecutorWithQueueSizeLimit, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._work_queue = queue.Queue(maxsize=maxsize)
```

Comment: I didn't downvote it but like I commented, the jobs in the queue are effectively controlled by the number of jobs have submitted, by limiting the max size of the queue, but not control number of jobs, you would run into a deadlock very likely.

Comment: I don't agree that you would *very likely* end in a deadlock. It might happen in some cases where the task being run uses *the same threadpool instance* to run another task.

Comment: python's queue and multiprocessing modules also provide Queues with options to limit their size, so there's no problem with that for sure.

Comment: On line 4, What type is `Queue.Queue(..)` ? I'm confused, does this mean any queue or was it meant to be `queue.Queue(..)`.?

Comment: @Queuebee that is correct, here is a working version of this code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66984088/2620402

Comment: Doesn't it reintroduce https://bugs.python.org/issue32576?

Comment: It won't work due to artificially queued `None` at the end of the `ThreadPoolExecutor.shutdown()` (see the queue.py for details). The `SimpleQueue()` won't bother about it, but the `Queue` will do and this will deadlock the class upon termination. So it's required to tweak the `shutdown()` method as well and add something like `self._work_queue.get(block=False)`. Probably, this will make the approach too tricky to use.

Answer (score 8):

You should use a semaphore, as demonstrated here https://www.bettercodebytes.com/theadpoolexecutor-with-a-bounded-queue-in-python/

One possible issue with **andres.riancho's** answer, is that if `max_size` is reached when trying to shutdown the pool, `self._work_queue.put(None)` (see excerpt below) may block, effectively making the shutdown *synchronous*.

```
    def shutdown(self, wait=True):
        with self._shutdown_lock:
            self._shutdown = True
            self._work_queue.put(None)
        if wait:
            for t in self._threads:
                t.join(sys.maxint)
```

Comment: This package https://github.com/mowshon/bounded_pool_executor uses the semaphore approach, with the standard `multiprocessing.BoundedSemaphore`/`threading.BoundedSemaphore` implementations.

Answer (score 2):

I tried to edit the accepted answer so it would actually run, but this was rejected for some reason. However, here is a working/simpler version of the accepted answer (corrected indentation, corrected `Queue.Queue` to `queue.Queue`, simplified unnecessarily verbose super call, added imports):

```
from concurrent import futures
import queue

class ThreadPoolExecutorWithQueueSizeLimit(futures.ThreadPoolExecutor):
    def __init__(self, maxsize=50, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._work_queue = queue.Queue(maxsize=maxsize)
```

Comment: Your solution works great, but when all threads are terminated and we go after the "with" which declares the ThreadPoolExecutorWithQueueSizeLimit, code seems to do an infinite loop. Any idea ? Thanks

Comment: @Cyril Sorry, I haven't encountered that issue with this

Comment: @Cyril I was encountering this problem, too. If you call `shutdown()` (which the `with` does implicitly) before the last future completes, there's some type of interaction between the future trying do a put on the queue and a behavior within the Queue itself. See my submission for a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

I've been doing this by chunking the range.
Here's a working example.

```
from time import time, strftime, sleep, gmtime
from random import randint
from itertools import islice
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed

def nap(id, nap_length):
    sleep(nap_length)
    return nap_length


def chunked_iterable(iterable, chunk_size):
    it = iter(iterable)
    while True:
        chunk = tuple(islice(it, chunk_size))
        if not chunk:
            break
        yield chunk


if __name__ == '__main__':
    startTime = time()

    range_size = 10000000
    chunk_size = 10
    nap_time = 2

    # Iterate in chunks.
    # This consumes less memory and kicks back initial results sooner.
    for chunk in chunked_iterable(range(range_size), chunk_size):

        with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=chunk_size) as pool_executor:
            pool = {}
            for i in chunk:
                function_call = pool_executor.submit(nap, i, nap_time)
                pool[function_call] = i

            for completed_function in as_completed(pool):
                result = completed_function.result()
                i = pool[completed_function]

                print('{} completed @ {} and slept for {}'.format(
                    str(i + 1).zfill(4),
                    strftime("%H:%M:%S", gmtime()),
                    result))

    print('==--- Script took {} seconds. ---=='.format(
        round(time() - startTime)))
```

[image]

The downside to this approach is the chunks are synchronous. All threads in a chunk must complete before the next chunk is added to the pool.

Answer (score 0):

I tried @bob-whitelock's solution, but had some thread hanging problems on shutdown. Here's a solution that uses a semaphore and the future's done callback to maintain the maximum number of items in progress.

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from threading import Semaphore

class BoundedThreadPoolExecutor(ThreadPoolExecutor):
    def __init__(self, max_size=50, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._semaphore = Semaphore(max_size)

    def submit(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._semaphore.acquire()
        future = super().submit(*args, **kwargs)
        future.add_done_callback(lambda _: self._semaphore.release())
        return future
```