# How do I reduce the number of connections requests created by a multithreaded Django request?

Tags: python, django, django-models

My project is roughly set up like this

```
thread_pool = ThreadPoolExecutor()

def my_background_thread(model: MyModel): 
     # Other DB Reads here
     ...

     # Some long running action here, spawning several threads
     ...
    
     # Save result of action to DB 
     model.field = val 
     model.save()

     # Other DB writes 
     ...
   
    

def my_view(request):
   model = MyModel.objects.get(...)
   
   thread_pool.submit(my_background_thread, model)

   # Return before thread has completed 
   return HttpResponse("success")
```

Unfortunately, because of the way I've set it up, Django is creating far too many DB connections -- more than necessary and exceeding my DB limits.

Some things that are not clear:

- When I pass model to the new thread, does it create a new connection at that point? Does it create a new connection only when I read / write to the model? Only when I write?
- How do I check the number of open connections, or show when a connection is created?

In short, how can I prevent Django from creating too many connections in this scenario?

EDIT: To clarify, the problem is that the bottleneck should be the multi-threaded, IO bound work, and the DB load should be relatively small in comparison. However, Django is opening too many connections and/or persisting the connections longer than it should, which is bottlenecking the IO-bound work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ThreadPoolExecutor: how to limit the queue maxsize?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48263704/threadpoolexecutor-how-to-limit-the-queue-maxsize)

Comment: No it doesn't unfortunately -- the problem is I want the queue size to be medium / large, but my parallelism is heavily limited by the maximum DB connections, even though this shouldn't be the bottleneck.

Comment: consult documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/databases/#caveats and also check pgbouncer

Comment: I've seen that documentation, but it's unclear. For example, is what I'm doing "a long-running process, outside of Django’s request-response cycle", and if so, how do I explicitly close the connection of the model? @iklinac